# macOS: how to enable "All Applications" in Application chooser dialog (Open with > Other...)

Tags: macos, finder, application-launch, dialog, open

I am trying to find the correct configuration command to enable "All Applications" by default when in the application chooser dialog (after selecting "other" from the "open with" context menu).

I am pretty sure this command would be part of the com.apple.finder.plist file but I cannot find it by myself.

macOS has been defaulting to the "Recommended Applications" option which is not useful when you have many applications that are able to read or write a file but macOS does not know that.

Any help very much appreciated.

P.S. All my searches so far have yielded results only for changing the default Application (and / or making that change permanent). Apologies if this problem has been solved already!